# Strange behavior with per-triangle collision in XNA

Tags: xna, collision, mesh

I have been working on a (somewhat) more advanced collision detection (and sliding response) in XNA that reads the VertexBuffer of any loaded model and from its vertices(and indices) generates instances of Planes... more objectively a custom Face struct made of one main plane that represents the actual face, and three more that represent its bounds.

In this way, when a BoundingSphere intersects the BoundingBox generated for each 3 vertices,
another intersection with the main Plane of the face is checked, after that, to be sure that the collision is happening inside the triangle, the other three planes, which are meant to be aligned with the triangle's edges, check for the BoundingSphere not to be outside.

So far I got interestingly good results with complex meshes, being able to scale, rotate and move them in realtime without ruining the collision mesh in the transformation process... but I believe my problem lies within the part where the faces are generated, for I only get correct-actually near perfect- results with half of the triangles that compose the mesh, that also depends on which mesh it is. With a few random geometric shapes I didn't have that problem.

It's like some of the normal of one or more planes inside the Face struct are being flipped resulting in the BoundingSphere reporting absolutely no collision with that certain triangles...

There's got to be some little thing somewhere... else I wouldn't have the sphere already colliding with such precision with the triangles that do work...

For now I just want to get this little big thing working, then I'll think of optimizing it...

[Source Files](http://www.mediafire.com/?auccwgwqfuca61e)